# Commas in list of names in a brochure

Tags: commas

I am putting together brochure for an event and we need to list people who are part a committee. If the info for each individual was going to be one line, I would put commas between the person's name, title and organization. But due to the format of the page, this info has to wrap onto two lines. We are making the line break after the person's title -- question, does the comma remain after the title even though we break onto another line or can I get rid of that comma?

EXAMPLE:

Here's how the info would appear if all on one line:

```
     John Smith, President, ACME Corporation
```

Here's how we currently have it formatted on the page with a line break:

```
    John Smith, President
    ACME Corporation
```

The full page would look something like this (with multiple people listed) -- do I put a comma after the title or not?

```
    John Smith, President
    ACME Corporation

    Jane Smith, President
    NEW Corporation

    Bill Smith, Vice President
    OLD Corporation
```